# Declare content of Intent in layout for value of TextView

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

All

I'm new to Android, but have some Java experience.

I'm working through the standard lessons, and I've created the 2 basic Activities with the EXTRA_MESSAGE String passing between the activities and being displayed.

The content of the first Activity is static and declared in the layout file. The content of the second Activity is dynamic ( based on the value entered in an EditText on the first Activity ) and is built in the onCreate() method in the second Activity.

Is is possible to define the dynamic content in the layout file ? Something like:
android:text="the value of EXTRA_MESSAGE in the Intent that is passed to this Activity" ?

I understand the lesson is showing me two ways of doing things, but is this do-able ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mean this:

```
android:text="@string/EXTRA_MESSAGE"
```

You can also set the text programmatacly:

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_mytext);
myText.setText("This value will be shown");

//Or if you defined a static string in another Activity 

myText.setText(FirstActivity.stringName);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying ObAt. I think the first option will require me to define a static string, which is not what I'm looking for. I understand I can programmatically set the text, but I'm trying to determine whether I HAVE to do that. ie Is it possible to declare all content ( even dynamic content ) in the layout XML.

Comment: If I can help you with something just ask!

Comment: Are you able to answer the question ?

Comment: I do not fully understand the question, but it is possible to get the text of an EditText and pass it to another Activity

Comment: The content of the second view is defined in the Activity class dynamically:

Comment: The content of the first Activity is defined in the layout XML. The content for the second Activity is defined in the onCreate() method ( ie in the Class definition, not the xml ) and grabs the dynamic content in the Intent. Can I declare the dynamic content from the Intent in the xml for the second Activity ?   So instead of `android:text="@string/EXTRA_MESSAGE"` I declare `android:text"insert the value of EXTRA_MESSAGE from the Intent that is passed to this Activity"` ?

Comment: I've been looking around for the answer to this and cant find any reference to  declaring dynamic content in XML. This isn't a requirement and  I guess it makes sense that XML only defines static data, but it would be good to have all content defined in one place. I

Comment: If you have dynamic data the best way to store it is in a (static) ArrayList, you can read it with a simple for loop.